# How to convert bytearray in python 2.7 to decimal string?

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-2.7, decimal

I have the following byte array

```
>>> string_ba
bytearray(b'4\x00/\t\xb5')
```

which is easily converted to hex string with the next 2 lines:

```
hex_string = [chr(x).encode('hex') for x in string_ba]
hex_string = ''.join(hex_string)
```

that return

```
>>> hex_string.lower()
'34002f09b5'
```

which is expected. (This is an RFID card signature)

I convert this to decimal by doing the above and then converting from hex string to decimal string (padded with zeroes) with the next line. I have a limit of 10 characters in string, so I'm forced to remove the first 2 characters in the string to be able to convert it to, at most, 10 character decimal number.

```
dec_string = str(int(hex_string[2:], 16)).zfill(10)
>>> dec_string
'0003082677'
```

which is correct, as I tested this with an online converter (hex: 002f09b5, dec: 3082677)
The question is, if there's a way to skip converting from bytearray to hex_string, to obtain a decimal string. In other words to go straight from bytearray to dec_string

This will be running on Python 2.7.15.

```
>>> sys.version
'2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) \n[GCC 7.3.0]'
```

I've tried removing the first element from bytearray and then converting it to string directly and joining. But this does not provide the desired result.

```
string_ba = string_ba[1:]
test_string = [str(x) for x in string_ba]
test_dec_string = ''.join(test_string).zfill(10)

>>> test_dec_string
'0000479181'
```

To repeat the question is there a way to go straight from bytearray to decimal string

Comment: So the first part of the hex string should be ignored(if it doesn't fit in the 10 decimal digits)? And the conversion should be byte oriented? (considering that each hex digit could be converted individually, and that would yield a different result)

Comment: @CristiFati yes. That's the idea. edit: Actually, I completly ignore the first byte and create the 10 decimal digit string from the 4 left. I don't understand the byte oriented question. Can you rephrase it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use struct library to convert bytearray to decimal. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142915/converting-a-bytearray-into-an-integer maybe help you

Answer (score 1):

A number (let's call it ***X***) consisting of ***n*** digits (in a base, let's refer to it as ***B***) is written as:

***D<sub>n-1</sub>D<sub>n-2</sub>D<sub>n-3</sub>...D<sub>2</sub>D<sub>1</sub>D<sub>0</sub>*** (where each *D<sub>i</sub>* is a digit in base *B*)

and its value can be computed based on the formula:

**V<sub>X</sub> = Σ<sub>i</sub><sup>n</sup><sub>=</sub><sup>-</sup><sub>0</sub><sup>1</sup>(B<sup>i</sup> * D<sub>i</sub>)** (notice that in this example the number is traversed *from right to left* - the traversing sense doesn't affect the final value).

As an example, number ***2468 (B<sub>10</sub>) = 10<sup>0</sup> * 8 + 10<sup>1</sup> * 6 + 10<sup>2</sup> * 4 + 10<sup>3</sup> * 2*** (*= 8 + 60 + 400 + 2000*).

An ***ASCII* string** is actually a **number in base *256* (*0x100*)**, where each char (byte) is a digit.

Here's an alternative based on the above:

- It only performs mathematical operations on integers (the conversion to string is done only at the end)
- The traversing sense (from above) is helpful with the restriction (final (decimal) number must fit in a number of digits, and in case of overflow the **most significant ones are to be ignored**)
- The algorithm is simple, starting from the right, compute the partial number value, until reaching the maximum allowed value, or exhausting the number digits (string chars)

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys 


DEFAULT_MAX_DIGITS = 10


def convert(array, max_digits=DEFAULT_MAX_DIGITS):
    max_val = 10 ** max_digits
    number_val = 0
    for idx, digit in enumerate(reversed(array)):
        cur_val = 256 ** idx * digit
        if number_val + cur_val > max_val:
            break
        number_val += cur_val
    return str(number_val).zfill(max_digits)


def main():
    b = bytearray("4\x00/\t\xb5")
    print("b: {:}\n".format(repr(b)))
    for max_digits in range(6, 15, 2):
        print("Conversion of b (with max {:02d} digits): {:}{:s}".format(
            max_digits, convert(b, max_digits=max_digits),
            " (!!! Default case - required in the question)" if max_digits == DEFAULT_MAX_DIGITS else ""
        ))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Outpput**:

> ```
> (py_064_02.07.15_test0) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054091895>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_02.07.15_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> b: bytearray(b'4\x00/\t\xb5')
>
> Conversion of b (with max 06 digits): 002485
> Conversion of b (with max 08 digits): 03082677
> Conversion of b (with max 10 digits): 0003082677 (!!! Default case - required in the question)
> Conversion of b (with max 12 digits): 223341382069
> Conversion of b (with max 14 digits): 00223341382069
> ```